# Report Builder 3.0 Count Expression Hide Label if 0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using a Bar Chart. My Chart Data Value is a single property that has a value of either "True" or "False". I have a working expression `=COUNT(IIF(Fields!MyFieldName.Value="True", 1, Nothing))`. However, if I have a single item in my graph, my label will display 0. I need to adjust my expression to not display anything instead of 0.

I have another similar working example I use in another report `=IIF(Count(Fields!MyFieldName.Value)=0,"",Count(Fields!MyFieldName.Value))`. This remove the 0 however I can't for the life of me figure out how to combine the two expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF( COUNT(IIF(Fields!MyFieldName.Value="True", 1, Nothing)) > 0
    , COUNT(IIF(Fields!MyFieldName.Value="True", 1, Nothing))
    , "")
```

To simplify things, you could also create a calculated field on your dataset that does this checking. Then in the chart you could just reference that new column.

Comment: That expression does exactly what I needed. I was trying to combine my two expressions and came close to this a few times but couldn't get it quite right. Thank you!